# Why is the Synchronized Block invalidated?

Tags: java, arraylist, thread-safety, synchronized, synchronized-block

As known that List is not thread-safe, I add synchronized to the code in 2 methods shown below.

1.

```
public class TestSyn 
{ 
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException 
  {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) 
    {
      new Thread( 
        ()->
        {
          synchronized( list )
          {
            list.add( Thread.currentThread().getName() );
          }
        } ).start();
    }
    Thread.sleep( 2000 );
    System.out.println( list.size() );
  }
}
```

2. 

```
public class TestSyn2 
{
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException 
  {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    synchronized( list )
    {
      for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) 
      {
        new Thread( () -> list.add( Thread.currentThread().getName() ) )
          .start();
      }
    }
    Thread.sleep( 2000 );
    System.out.println( list.size() );
  }
}
```

The result of the first method was always 10000 which was correct,while the second one sometimes is less than 10000.

So, why does the second one cannot output the right result?

Comment: because you are creating threads inside the synchronized block. But what do you mean by "invalidated"?

Comment: why is 10_000 correct for first code?  I would expect 100_000 -- anyway, second code has no synchronization between the Threads (having the threads created or started inside a synchronized block does NOT make the threads synchronized - only the `main` thread will be *protected* by the synchronized statement)

Comment: The threads in the second sample are accessing the list concurrently without any synchronisation, so that under some circumstances some additions to the list can get lost. The monitor is held by the main thread, but the generated threads don't care about that fact, because the will never enter a synchronized block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding on the answer that already was provided in comments (above).

---

The difference between your two versions is in which thread or threads lock the `list` object's intrinsic mutex.

In the first version, the `synchronized(list)` statement is executed by each one of the 100,000 new threads that your program creates. It is lexically contained within the lambda expression that generates the `Runnable` delegates for each of the new threads.

In the second version, the `synchronized(list)` statement is only ever executed one time, by the program's `main` thread. It appears outside of the lambda. The 100,000 new threads mutate the shared list without any synchronization, and the fact that `main()` executes inside the `synchronized` block means nothing because no other thread ever tries to synchronize on the same object.

---

**Also note:** Although the first version of your program is "safe," it also is kind of pointless. None of your 100,000 new threads ever does anything at all outside of the `synchronized` block. That means, none of your 100,000 new threads ever does anything concurrently with any of the others. But concurrency is the *only* reason for creating threads.

Comment: Well, how could I optimize the first version?

Comment: @liuzx, Your code creates a list of 100,000 strings\* that will match an unspecified pattern. You could improve that by (1) write explicit code to generate the strings, and document the pattern. And (2) either don't use threads at all or, if generating the strings takes a lot of time,\*\* use a thread _pool_ to parallelize the string creation, but don't put anything inside a `synchronized` block that doesn't need to be done serially. I.E., synchronize `list.add(new_name)` but do not synchronize the code that builds the `new_name`.

Comment: \*I would call them _thread names,_ but they won't be the names of any live threads. All the threads will be dead by the time you use the list. Nothing will remain of them but the names.

Comment: \*\*It won't take enough time to make threading worth while.

Comment: @liuzx, see my updated answer to see why even your first version is not truly "safe."

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Thread t;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                t = new Thread();
                String new_name = t.getName();
                synchronized (list){
                    t.start();
                    list.add(new_name);
                }
            }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }   ----According to the first method(1) of ur first comment, I changed my code shown above,  does it match?

Comment: @liuzx, The version in your comment (immediately above) _is_ thread safe because only one of ten thousand and one threads does anything at all. The `synchronized` block is pointless because only one thread ever enters it, but it also is harmless. I can't answer, "does it match?" though. Match what? I can't tell whether you are trying to accomplish something or trying to prove something. Either way, I can't guess what it is. The code in the comment creates ten thousand threads that do nothing just so that you can make a list of their names. I can't guess why you would want to do that.